# Массовая смена автора документа

Tags: linux, bash, office, open-office, libre-office

Подскажите как быть)

Предыстория:

```
У друга на работе уволился админ и на компе, буха, юрика
и самого директора, изменил пользователя на Х%Й Булыжников или Пися
Камушкин - не суть)
Но обнаружили это через неделю или две, когда открыли документы doc,
odt,xsl  и прочие офисные, нажали файл - Свойства и там увидели сие
чудо) а файлы они эти куда-то шлют и там через эту процедуру, даты
сверяют в случае чего,)
```

Как можно массово такие офисные файлы перевладеть (сменить или убрать автора)?)

Руками долго (создать новый док, перекинуть все в него и сохранить - их
там сотни документов) естественно, теперь Пользователь нормальный, но
документы некоторые остались с пасхалкой)))

Подскажите, как под linux  или windows  можно автоматически поменять.

Думаю что скриптом можно, но не пойму как работать с api или самой libreOffice  из консоли

Спасибо...

p.s. как выяснилось - админа очень обидели... и потом поняли что не
правы, но было поздно)

Конвертировать в другой формат, в надежде смены автора так же безсмысленно

```
libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///home/firefedot/.config/libreoffice-alt --headless --convert-to odt *.doc
```

В итоге остался тот же автор создания документа и те же авторы изменений.

Comment: Под виндой возьмите js, почитайте Excel.Application. `new ActiveXObject('Excel.Application')`. Вам понадобится ф-ция Load, Save и Quit.

Comment: ага, спасибо.. осталось винду найти.. но я понял... но надо чтоб стоял MS Office?

Comment: Excel.Application  находится в пакете офиса, на машине должен быть установлен офис, который может прочесть ваш excel.

Comment: А, понял...Спасибо

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо @Qwertiy за подсказку.

В общем пока что вариант такой нашел.
Сначала приводим все нужные файлы к типу odt, таким образом

```
libreoffice -env:UserInstallation=file:///home/firefedot/.config/libreoffice-alt --headless --convert-to odt *.doc
```

Затем можно скриптом, а можно и руками, делаем так.
Распаковывем наш файл ODT  в папку

```
unzip file.odt -d folder
```

После этого ищем и заменяем нужного/ненужного автора

```
 grep NONAMES meta.xml --color
 # Или если не знаем имени, то 
 grep creator meta.xml --color
```

И мы увидим нужное нам, оно будет подсвечено)

Заменяем все что нужно

```
sed -i 's/NONAMES/MyName/g' meta.xml
```

Затем, мы приводим завершающие действия.
Запаковываем все обратно, в два этапа, для правильной структуры нового файла

1:

```
cd folder
zip -0 -X file.odt mimetype
```

2:

```
zip -r file.odt * -x mimetype
```

После этого  файл открывается без ошибки и если открыть меню Файл-Свойства, мы увидим того автора,которого внесли.

Осталось проверить как это все работает именами файлов содержащие пробелы.

p.s. если @Qwertiy возражает, то могу все это передать ему в ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Odt-файл - это zip-архив. Надо его распаковать как zip-архив, найти, в каком месте там находится имя пользователя, поменять и упаковать обратно. Аналогично с docx (но не doc).

PS: Делал так с vsdx.

Comment: А чем его распаковать? что-то пока не найду что его  поймет. Переименование в другое расширение не дало результата естественно. Какой-то пакет может нужен?

Comment: @Трезвый, любой архиватор, умеющий zip.

Comment: Точно, что-то прогнал ... unzip смог... а обратно, так же? указываю все папки и в odt?

Comment: @Трезвый, да. Только с методами сжатия не мудри. И упаковывать надо файлы в папке, а не папку.

Comment: да, собрал обратно zip -0 file.odt *   и он его собрал, при открытии он ругается ,Что он битый, восстанавливает. но автор на нового не меняется. хотя старый и пропадает. В общем вроде нормально.но ошибка при открытии на прягает .. может надо какую-то степерь сжатия? я без нее сделала пока ..

Comment: @Трезвый, а кодировка правильная при записи нового автора? Если не получится, я чуть позже проверю.

Comment: Внутри файла meta.xml UTF-8 и в консоле кодировка у меня UTF-8..  или надо как то еще  раз сменить кодировку? но сам файл имеет meta.xml: text/xml; charset=us-ascii

Comment: Спасибо. сейчас выложу ответом ...